# Handling dynamic request response of third party services in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We have our application written using Spring Boot.

We are integrating with various other third party services, such that request and response of each third party service is different.

Number of these third party services are dynamic and will keep on increasing with time. We don't want to create a request and response class every time when a service is added and thinking to have a generic solution for same.
What we are thinking is if somehow request and response is made configurable (variable fields being read from xml, json file or from db) and on the fly java class can be created out for a service, so that next time a new service need to be integrated we will just configure request and response fields from a configuration source and there no need to touch code base.

[Service can have xml or json based request response].

Any lead on this can we really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make your request response handling in DAO class and for test use different DAO injected using different Spring profiles as prod and test.

Other solution is using mock DAO using mockito for example that will just return your expected response

Comment: could you pls elaborate a bit more. I guess, by your  approach, if i need to integrate a new third party service then i need to add a new dao class and request and response classes for this service. i want to avoid that and have a generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this kind of thing being done in our project creating some eclipse plugin.

Comment: can u pls tell the name of plugin. it will be of great help.